# self join query which gives count of join record and their ids

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle11gr2

I have a table on oracle database for exp. EMPLOYEE which has following data:

| ID | EMPID | NAME | manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EM1 | ana | EM3 |
| 2 | EM2 | john |  |
| 3 | EM3 | ravi | EM2 |
| 4 | EM4 | das | EM2 |
| 5 | EM5 | michael | EM3 |

empid is a unique column and Manager column store empid of manage,  so now I have to select a manager id and count of employee under them and empid of then in one row like

| EMPID | COUNT | EMP1 | EMP2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ME2 | 2 | EM3 | EM4 |

What I was able to achieve:

```
select 
  e2.empid as manager,
  e2.name manger_name,
  count(*) over (partition by e2.empid) as employee_count,
  e1.empid as employee,
  e1.name as employee_name
  from employee e1 left join employee e2 on e1.manager = e2.empid
```

| MANAGER | MANGER_NAME | EMPLOYEE_COUNT | EMPLOYEE | EMPLOYEE_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EM2 | john | 2 | EM4 | das |
| EM2 | john | 2 | EM3 | ravi |
| EM3 | ravi | 2 | EM5 | michael |
| EM3 | ravi | 2 | EM1 | ana |
| null | null | 1 | EM2 | john |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HQhewPFK)

can anyone suggest how can I achieve this result in oracle sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL (in all dialects, not just Oracle's) you need to know how many columns there are going to be in the output; therefore it is impossible to dynamically generate columns for an unknown number of employees under each manager.

If you only want to show 2 employees then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT manager AS empid,
         empid AS emp,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY manager) AS cnt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY manager ORDER BY empid) AS rn
  FROM   employee
  WHERE  manager = 'EM2'
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(emp)
  FOR rn IN (1 AS emp1, 2 AS emp2)
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (ID, EMPID, NAME, manager) AS
SELECT 1, 'EM1', 'ana',     'EM3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'EM2', 'john',    NULL  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'EM3', 'ravi',    'EM2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'EM4', 'das',     'EM2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'EM5', 'michael', 'EM3' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| EMPID | CNT | EMP1 | EMP2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EM2 | 2 | EM3 | EM4 |

---

If you want all the employees of a manager (and a count of the total) then use rows, not columns:

```sql
SELECT manager AS empid,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY manager) AS cnt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY manager ORDER BY empid) AS index_of_emp,
       empid AS emp
FROM   employee
WHERE  manager = 'EM2';
```

Which outputs:

| EMPID | CNT | INDEX_OF_EMP | EMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EM2 | 2 | 1 | EM3 |
| EM2 | 2 | 2 | EM4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c-tO51fc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select manager, count(empid) as count, 
listagg(empid, ',' ) within group (order by empid) as employees 
from employee
where (manager is not null)
group by manager order by manager;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mnUStztv)

For readers using >=18c: in case JSON is fine, you can use:

```
select manager, count(empid) as count, 
json_objectagg(key 'emp'||to_char(rn) value empid) as employees 
from
  (select manager, empid, 
     row_number() over (partition by manager order by empid) as rn
   from employee
   where (manager is not null))
group by manager order by manager;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iZ9fVbDW)